# How can I most effectively destroy enemy turrets?

Tags: nuclear-dawn

In *Nuclear Dawn*, the enemy commander can place turrets (rocket or machine-gun) or other various structures to benefit their team.

The problem I've run into is: **I can't destroy them.** I've tried grenades, every last bit of ammo as an EXO, even when working *with* a teammate to take one down. But the health of the structure seems to freeze at quarter-health.

**How can I destroy these turrets?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best approach is to use Siege Kits. Kits are "subclasses" for the 4 possible classes.

Your commander needs to research them, otherwise they are unavailable.

As siege weapons count:

- The Grenade Launcher for the Soldier Class
- The LAW/Pulse Cannon for the Exo Class.
- The Saboteur Kit for the Stealth Class, but that one is less effective.

With those weapons every tower falls after a few shots.

But as always in ND: Teamwork wins.

As a sidenote:

You can kill a Tower with 2 Handgrenades if they explode in the moment they unpack from that crate to the tower. It is, however, very tricky and I never managed to do that. But it works.

Comment: Pre-advanced kits (for example if you get a level 1 commander that first builds 10 MG turrets in your base before even getting a spawn) you can drop an ammo pack, throw EMP grenade, get the refill on the Grenade from the ammo pack and then repair tool,EMP again,repair tool and hope to survive long enough. However, that is very risky and only a last resort.